# Left Join in MySQL returns null values while they shouldn't be

Tags: mysql, join, null

So I'm writing a small school project with MySQL. The general idea is to have a simple website that displays text in html squares, where the data about them is taken from the database (the displayed text, and the background color of the square).

My code for now looks like this:

The table with squares:

```
CREATE TABLE `display` (
  `display_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `showcased_text` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_color` int(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table with colors:

```
CREATE TABLE `kolory` (
  `color_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `color_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `color_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There is also a code which makes a relation between these two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE `display`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `display_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`assigned_color`) REFERENCES `colors` (`color_id`);
COMMIT;
```

And so far it works good...
But when I try to "print" a table in PHPMyAdmin which contains only displayed text from "display" table and assigned color code, all color codes are returned as NULL.

```
The code looks like that:
SELECT display.showcased_text, colors.color_code
FROM display
  LEFT JOIN colors ON display.assigned_color = colors.color_code
```

I tried to work with CAST like that too, like that:

```
SELECT display.showcased_text, colors.color_code
FROM display
  LEFT JOIN colors ON cast(display.assigned_color as VARCHAR(50)) = colors.color_code
```

But then MySQL returns a syntax error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're joining on the wrong field. `display.assigned_color = colors.color_code` should be `display.assigned_color = colors.color_id`, since the foreign key reference is from `display.assigned_color` to `colors.color_id`

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to join on `color_code` field in `colors` Table. Instead it should be on `color_id` field in `colors` Table.

```
SELECT display.showcased_text, colors.color_code
FROM display
  LEFT JOIN colors ON display.assigned_color = colors.color_id
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! :D Can't believe it was so obvious...
Beginners mistakes I guess. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Query 1,you have used wrong condition to join

```
SELECT display.showcased_text, colors.color_code
FROM display
  LEFT JOIN colors ON display.assigned_color = colors.color_id
```

in query 2,don't understand why are you using cast in join condition